# How to draw lines between letters

Tags: border

I want to draw a line in text just as in [this picture](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/78/EcoRI_restriction_enzyme_recognition_site.svg). No colours needed, everything black on white. The relative positions of the letters need to stay the same - no shifting allowed.

I've tried a solution using tabular but since there doesn't seem to be a way to dynamically add/remove vertical lines between cells I had to give up.

Glad about any help.

Comment: And one minute after posting I found the solution. I can dynamically add vertical lines using the multicolumn tag.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Beside solution with table also are other solution, for example drawing with `pstrick` or `tikz`.

Comment: It would be great if you shared the answer you found.

Comment: Adding vertical lines adds shifting (of at least line thickness).

Comment: You can also use `tikzmark` to do this. This allows you to separate the text and the drawing.

Answer (score 4):

Some juggling with `tabular` parameters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\lb}[1]{\makebox[1em]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{10pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{c}}
\lb{G} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\lb{A}} & \lb{A} & \lb{T} & \lb{T} & \lb{C} \\
\cline{2-5}
\lb{C} & \lb{T} & \lb{T} & \lb{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\lb{A}} & \lb{G}
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `pstricks`:  it consists in making each letter  a box  with 12 nodes, and connecting the relevant nodes with the `\ncangle` command:

```
\documentclass[12pt, x11names]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
\sffamily\Large
G\psDefBoxNodes{T}{\,A}\,A\,T\,T\,C \\
C\,T\,T\,A\,A\,\psDefBoxNodes{B}{G}
\ncangle[angleA=-90, angleB=90, armB=1.75ex, linewidth=1.2pt, linejoin=1, linecolor=Green4!80]{T:tl}{B:bl}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

And solution with TikZ based on use of TikZ library `matrix:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,inner xsep=1pt,inner ysep=2pt,row sep=0pt]
{
G   &   A   &   A   &   T   &   T   &   C   \\
C   &   T   &   T   &   A   &   A   &   G   \\
};
\draw[thick,green]
    ([yshift=-2pt] m-1-1.north east) |- (m-2-5.north east) -- ([yshift=+2pt]m-2-5.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't use JPG for diagrams.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, just to know: why not?

Comment: JPG is designed to be used for photographs. It uses a lossy compression which is barely noticeable in photographs, but will produce obvious artefacts in non-photographic images like diagrams and computer screenshots with exact lines and solid-colour regions. PNG is designed for this kind of graphics, is very efficient with solid-colour regions and uses no lossy compression. See http://english.rejbrand.se/rejbrand/msword.asp#raster-graphics for more information.

Comment: At least to me, the JPG version of your image looks annoyingly distorted, especially at the top of the green line. See this non-interpolated magnification: http://privat.rejbrand.se/tex-dna-jpg.png. For a comparison, have a look at Bernard's PNG: http://privat.rejbrand.se/tex-dna-png.png

Comment: Do you have better suggestion hot to generate picture for showing here? Please, advice me. Technique should be simple and fast. This picture, taken from screen with Snipping Tool, is only approximation -- poor as you stated -- of real picture obtained by MWE in pdf format.

Comment: @Zarko: Do exactly as you did, but save the screenshot as a PNG image instead of a JPG image. (Use the file format drop-down list in the [Save dialog box](http://privat.rejbrand.se/saveaspng.png).) Since the Snipping Tool is used to create screenshots, the default file format is PNG (at least in Windows 7), so you probably changed it yourself to JPG...

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, thank you for your complains about image quality. Before I didn't notice, that the image format has been (actually that ad been me) change the save setting from default `png` to `jpg` ... now I correct settings and also upload image in my answer in new format. Now even me see that is better quality :-)

Comment: @Zarko: You're welcome. It looks perfect now! :)